# structuring data in numpy for ltsm (examples)

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

I am having problem with understanding how data should be prepared for different models:

1. One to many
2. Many to one
3. Many to many(A)
4. Many to many(B)

[image]

Is the right way to think o it this way. Shape numbers are no relevant and do not match the one on picture. I am just trying to understand logic behind.:

```
import numpy as np


#1. one to many
# X for input y for output

X = np.ones([10,1,5])
y = np.zeros([10,3]) #3 represnts size of output vector

#2. many to one

X = np.ones([10,5,5])
y = np.zeros([10,1])

#3. many to many

X = np.ones([10,5,5])
y = np.zeros([10,5])  

# in this case cell should be different than y. It must be bigger to shift some data

#4. many to many

X = np.ones([10,5,5])
y = np.zeros([10,5])

# in this case cell is the same shape as y
```

Comment: It depends a bit on the framework you are using (Tensorflow, Theano, Keras, PyTorch, you name it). Usually your output format needs to match the outer layer nodes and respective activation function, that's no different with lstm. However, sometimes, e.g. in seqtoseq things can be more complicated but there exist plenty of tutorials for pretty much every framework. And if you want to implement lstm yourself start with the math and work backwards to code from there.

Comment: @meow, I am not using any framework

Comment: without a framework your question does not make too much sense tbh. Look at the math and try to do toy examples, reading the formulas should give you a good intuition about what architecture requires which shapes, but be warned implementing an lstm network on your own will be relatively complicated, at least compared to a regular neural network.